# Unity 2D Multiplayer - Server-Client based

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, client-server, multiplayer

My idea of making a simple 2D game which can be played either single - or multiplayer.
The concept is really simple: the one creating the game is the host, the one joining is the client.

Questions/Problems:
 1. Which are the prerequisites to starting a project like this?
 2. How does Unity work with server-client based situations?
 3. Is it possible to implement networking manually by writing a script for it? ( not using 3rd party libs and packages )

Comment: This question is probably not about [tag:unityscript] since this is about a new game not an old deprecated language.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to define first how to connect these players altogether. If I were to do that game, I would have some sort of a back-end service that will serve as all the player's common ground.

Having a back-end server would not suffice though. You will have to have a real-time agent for the gameplay (unless if the game that you want is a turn-based system). This will ensure the synchronization of each player to your game.

Overall, if you had to ask these questions, well I don't think you're ready for this kind of scope. Well, surely if you're eager to do it, here are your answers:

1. Pre-requisites would be a Back-end server (that supports sockets), Real-time agents, a Multiplayer System architecture design (Not sure if this is the term. Well basically you will need to design some sort of system where you will define what, where, and how the data will interact with each other ie. Who will be the host, the server or the players?)
2. Unity works depending on how you want it to work. You could either use UNet or Photon as your real-time agent. (Believe me, this is not something that you would want to do on your own).
3. Yes, you can as long as you have the brains for it. You could use .NET network classes and connect to your backend services (your own backend) freely using .NET's networking api. I would only use this though for REST API for my backend and nothing else.

Again, there are things that you would rather be using such as Gamesparks, Playfab, UNet, Photon etc. I suggest trying to see what you need first and see if these backend-services/real-time services have it. If they don't, then that's the time that you make your own.

Answer (score 1):

Either you are making 2D or 3D game the main thing in multiplayer is BaaS (Backend as a service). you can write your own custom backend using your prefer server side language and database but its really difficult to manage for a long period. so we have short and fast way to do this by using some best BaaS.

here is the list.

1. [Playfab](https://playfab.com/)
2. [GameSparks](https://www.gamesparks.com/)
3. [Photon](https://www.photonengine.com/)

and more [here](https://blog.soomla.com/2016/02/top-10-parse-alternatives-game-backend.html)

You can simply Download their SDKs and import in your unity project by following their documentation.